# Fixed content-header in AdminLTE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I'm using [AdminLTE](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) with `sidebar-collapse fixed` in `<body>` and trying to make content-header fixed. So it will be floating like header. Here the HTML code :

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header row">
        <h1 class="col-md-6">
            Master Satuan
        </h1>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
            <button id="batchDelete" class="btn btn-danger mx-1">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
            </button>&nbsp;
            <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success mx-1" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    <!-- Content here ->
    </section>
 </div>
```

I have tried modify the css `content-header` with `position: fixed` but the header hidden in back of Main Content. And have tried the fixed header scrolling by [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp) with no luck because the header still hidden in the back of Main Content. Actually I just want a fixed position after Main Header. How I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: did you try z-index yet?

Comment: @DomenikReitzner not yet, let me try read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `posistion:fixed;` and `z-index`for your header.

And, Set `position:absolute;` for main contents. Set `top: some pixel values`